# Error prefixCls when Packaging a React Component with Antd and using it in another Project

Tags: reactjs, antd, rollup

I have a very simple component, that contains some **antd** (`Menu, SubMenu, Item`) components.

```
import { Menu } from "antd";

export const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Menu.SubMenu
          title={"Documentation"}
          key={"Documentation"}
          className={"docu-menuitem"}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="test">
            Test
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu.SubMenu>
      );
}
```

I then package it with rollup

rollup.config.js

```
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.js",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
      },
      {
        file: "dist/index.es.js",
        format: "es",
        exports: "named",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        plugins: [],
        minimize: true,
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: "node_modules/**",
        namedExports: {
          "node_modules/react-is/index.js": ["isFragment", "ForwardRef"],
        },
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        presets: [
          [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
              runtime: "automatic",
            },
          ],
        ],
      }),
      external(),
      resolve({ extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }),
    //   terser(),
    ],
  },
];
```

And then import it to another react project, created with vite.

Unfortunatelly, I am getting the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prefixCls')
> at InternalSubMenu2

The error happens in the internals

```
var _React$useContext = React.useContext(MenuContext$2),
prefixCls = _React$useContext.prefixCls,
...
```

I suspect this happens because of the `useContext` being null.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Apparently, if I wrap the `SubMenu` with a `Menu` component resolves the error. This does not help though, since I want to use a `Menu` to wrap this component in the project where I use this package. So I do not want to have a `Menu` wrapped within another `Menu`